# Why does my app sometimes create a file "A.myappextension-shm" in addition to the file "A.myappextension"?

Tags: macos, cocoa, core-data

I have a Document based Core Data app that saves with SQLite. While testing I save to a test file A.myappextension. Sometimes another file---"A.myappextension-shm"---is also created. Why is that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that `A.myappextension` is your Core Data persistent store file, it happens because of SQLite journaling. You might also see `A.myappextension-wal`. Both of these extra files are SQLite journal files, and a lot of your data may actually be stored in them instead of in the main file. If you ever copy these files, or remove them, or do anything else that treats them as files instead of SQLite data, you'll need to copy/remove/whatever all of them.

Comment: Thanx a million for your answer! I'm new to Core Data and finding the learning curve quite steep. What's the difference between the Core Data persistent store and the file that the user saves a document to? Or are they the same thing? What is the recommended way to handle the journaling files as I've never seen such files generated by other mac apps alongside the saved file? Thank again.

Comment: The persistent store file is the file that Core Data stores its data in. Any time Core Data saves to a file, it's saving to a persistent store. Your app might use that as a document, or it might do something different. The recommended way to handle journal files is to *not handle them*, just leave them alone. The only exceptions are the ones I mentioned-- if you copy or delete the persistent store, you should do the same to the journal files.

Comment: It seems untidy having potentially three files for every document: what if the user moves files in Finder without moving all three files? Also I would think that I have many applications on my mac that use SQLite as its persistent store format, but I've never seen them create `-shm` and `-wal` files.

Comment: This kind of situation is why OS X has file wrappers. Basically, an app can create a directory to hold its file contents but have it appear in the Finder as if it were a single file.